# Python Simple Program

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Simple Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596739/python-simple-program)

I am a new at programming and trying to learn python. I am trying to write a simple code but getting hard time.

so this is input text file

> A 1 2 3 4
>
> B 5 6 7 8
>
> C 9 10 11 12

Can someone help me with how can I output element of second and third column corresponding to the element of first column which I will enter? In other words, how should I write a program so when I enter "B" when programs asks me to enter a letter, program will out put "5" and "6" which are elements of second and third column corresponding to "B".

At least can someone give me some kind of hint on it, how can I approach this?

so far I have:

```
f=open('path of a file','r')

for line in f.readlines():

    data = line.split(' ')
    if len(data) == 5:
        #print data[0]
        letter=raw_input("Enter the letter")
        print letter
```

Comment: Unfortunately this question has a high chance of getting closed because it's a "I need help with everything" type of question, and it also sounds like homework. If it's homework, you have instructors/TAs/whatever available to you (hopefully), and otherwise, how much actual python have you done? Have you made it through, say, the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)?

Comment: If your teacher gave you this code, you should get them to read up on context managers

Comment: `.readlines()` is not necessary when iterating over the lines of a file. It just creates an intermediate list that is a waste of memory (even though it doesn't live very long).

Answer (score 2):

Please start with a beginner's tutorial such as the free http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

For your specific problem, are you wanting to draw that line graphically on the screen? If so, you'll need to work with a GUI toolkit of some sort as well.  I prefer [Qt](http://www.pyside.org/), but other options such as [GTK](http://www.pygtk.org/), [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/) and [Tk](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) are also viable.  If you don't need to draw it, it's just a simple math problem.

Start with the tutorial and ask another more specific question when you have some code that's not working or a specific design problem that is troubling you.

### Edit:

Here's some code based on what you provided to give you a basic structure to fill in

```
#open file
f=open('path of a file','r')

#some data structure to store the file data in.  A list or dictonary could both be useful.
my_data = ...

#populate data structure
for line in f.readlines():
    #put the line in my data structure in some way
    #splitting the line and storing the resulting list could be useful
    #again, a dictionary may be useful here too (indexed by the "code" value)


#get user input
letter=raw_input("Enter the letter")

#handle bad user input

#calculate what you need

#display output
```

Answer (score 1):

The '2nd' and '3rd' elements, in python, are different than the '2nd' and '3rd' elements you speak of here. In python, there is the `zeroth` element, so the 'first' element of `B` is actually `6`, not `5`.

Yes, it's strange, but that's just how it is.

The trick to solving this problem lies in the predictability of `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`; your problem states that there is going to be a list of element proceeding each line. Each of those will have at least three elements, meaning you can get the `[1]` and `[2]` elements of the list without running into an `IndexError`.

Like the other answers/comments suggest, pick up the python tutorial, and once you're halfway done, ask for some help from other classmates, or the teacher if you're still stuck.

Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach:

```
file = open('filename', 'r', 0)
dict = {}
for line in file:
    line = line.strip().split(' ')
    dict[line[0]] = (line[1], line[2])

letter = raw_input('Enter letter')
print dict[letter]
```

Of course, you can manipulate the tuple part and print.